# How to programmatically raise-to-top Visual Studio from Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, com

How do you programatically raise the VisualStudio environment from python?

You get a handle to Visual Studio as follows:

```
import win32com.client
>>> b = win32com.client.Dispatch('VisualStudio.DTE')
```

but what method of b needs to be called to make VisualStudio environment focused and raised-to-top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can get Visual Studio's main window:

```
w = b.MainWindow
```

Then you can get main window's handle (HWND):

```
h = w.Hwnd
```

Then using win32gui module you can move this window on top:

```
import win32gui
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(h)
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. What is a good source of documentation for these commands?

Comment: I have used this man page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.dte.aspx